# Api naming in microservices design

Tags: rest, microservices

Let's say that there are two microservices representing the resources orders(/orders) and customers(/customers). My requirement is to get all the orders made by a customer. 
Had it been a monolithic application, I would have modeled my uri as /customers/{id}/orders. This would have hit the customers resource and made an in-memory service call to get the corresponding orders. 
Now, in case of microservices, this isn't possible. So, is the only way to get the orders is to make a remote service call or is there a better way of doing it?
Can we create another resource with the representation /ordersByCustomers/{customerid}?

Comment: You might want to look into [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) and you might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You will probably find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful.

Comment: Actually I feel like this is a good, and interesting, question, but maybe more something for the programmers stackexchange rather than the stackoverflow section..
Although HATEOAS is interesting anyways

Comment: @Markus W Mahlberg: Stop being a total douche please.

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling I know the title sounds rude, but the essay really is worth a read – even for the most experienced. Seldomly have words be written which were so true. Try it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass some query parameters as filters (this is the most common way I've seen). For example

```
/orders?customerId=123
```

I think that's quite clear, that you want to retrieve all customer orders filtered by customer id. In the same way you can add pagination or other filters.

The important thing to remember is that you want the `order` resource, so the URL should remain the same. I'm mentioning this, because this has been the most difficult thing for me to change... to think about **resources** rather than remote calls.

Comment: This makes sense but the problem with filters is that it makes the resource more generic and if there are more query params, logic might get more complicated as well.Also, customer itself is a proper resource in which case will it still be correct to have it as a query parameter?

Comment: I think both customer and order are *independent* resources which are linked (I do think this is a very important aspect from a system point of view). If you want to delete a customer, do you want to delete their orders too? (with all the impact this might have on your finance systems?). For a similar read, I think this the same problem as in [aggregation vs composition](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/61527/17243). This also go hand in hand with Domain-Driven Design concept of [Bounded Context](http://dddcommunity.org/uncategorized/bounded-context/)

Answer (score 1):

In general you should beware of using endpoint that are more or less similar to the one you suggested:

```
/ordersByCustomers/{customerid}
```

Why? Because this is not RESTful in general (even in microservices environment) and make the API difficult to understand and you by the consumers. What if you need `orderByWhatever`? Will you be introducing new endpoint every single time you need a new set of data? Try to avoid so opinionated endpoints.

What @Augutsto suggested is fully correct. If you're afraid of having a complicated logic in `GET` request this is the situation where you can break REST rules. I mean introducing:

```
POST /orders/filter/
```

Where all the filtering logic will be passed in requests body - so it's easier to carry complicated logic as well.